# make webcam device invisible to a process

Tags: windows, powershell, winapi

Some context:

I have an application that opens the *first webcam device* on Windows 10 64bit (whatever index 0 is during enumeration of devices) and does some processing on the frames. The application's source code is not accessible.

Question:

I need to make this application to work with two webcams at the same time. I thought maybe there is a way to do the following:

1. hide webcam 2
2. run application (picks up webcam 1)
3. hide webcam 1, unhide webcam 2
4. run application (picks up webcam 2)

Is there a way to do this without interrupting camera's operation? Note that both applications are running at the same time so hard-disabling a camera is not an option. Calling either a Win32 api or doing this in PowerShell is acceptable.

Thanks!

Comment: think only way here inject dll to process on start, which hook `CM_Get_Device_Interface_List_ExW` (if application got webcam interface during interface enumeration) and fix result of call

Comment: Uh perfect! I thought about injecting a DLL. Did not know the exact API call (`CM_Get_Device_Interface_List_ExW `). Thanks.

Comment: sorry mistake - really - need hook [`CM_Get_Device_Interface_ListW`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/cfgmgr32/nf-cfgmgr32-cm_get_device_interface_listw) - this api will be called if application direct use *CM* api or SetupApi which is internal call *CM* api. in case application got interface name in some another way (which incorrect but possible) - here need to look how concrete

Comment: after hook - you will be have multiple, NULL-terminated Unicode strings. you need pass somehow info to dll (say via cmd line for example) - which string left in buffer and remove all another

Comment: Assuming the app is using such device/setup APIs, and not the simpler [AVICap](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/Multimedia/video-capture) API instead.

Comment: How can I trace these API calls to figure out the exact call? Is there a tool for that?

Comment: debugger - simply set bp on api call

Comment: *and not the simpler AVICap API instead* not look for this api, but probably it internal anyway use *CM* api for enumerate interfaces

Comment: I can confirm that the application is calling `CM_Get_Device_Interface_ListW `. I verified by using "API monitor v2 64bit" attached to the process.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to comments on my original question, I managed to solve my problem by hooking into `CM_Get_Device_Interface_List_ExW` Win32 API call.

I had to verify what API is being called, so I used and API tracer tool (API monitor v2 64bit). Debugger should work too but for some reason my VS debugger did not show me any symbols (possibly missing pdbs).

The original process I tried to hook into is written in C# so I hooked into the call via an injected C# DLL containing [EasyHook](https://easyhook.github.io/). Here is my code snippet (actual injection code left out):

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

using EasyHook;

public class HookDevices : IEntryPoint
{
    LocalHook FunctionLocalHook;

    // construct this to hook into calls
    HookDevices()
    {
        try
        {
            FunctionLocalHook = LocalHook.Create(
                LocalHook.GetProcAddress("CfgMgr32.dll", "CM_Get_Device_Interface_List_ExW"),
                new FunctionHookDelegate(CM_Get_Device_Interface_List_Ex_Hooked),
                this);
            FunctionLocalHook.ThreadACL.SetExclusiveACL(new Int32[] { 0 });
        }
        catch (Exception ExtInfo)
        {
            Debug.LogException(ExtInfo);
            return;
        }
    }

    [UnmanagedFunctionPointer(CallingConvention.StdCall,
        CharSet = CharSet.Unicode,
        SetLastError = true)]
    delegate uint FunctionHookDelegate(
        ref Guid interfaceClassGuid,
        string deviceID,
        IntPtr buffer,
        uint bufferLength,
        uint flags,
        IntPtr hMachine);

    [DllImport("CfgMgr32.dll",
        CharSet = CharSet.Unicode,
        SetLastError = true,
        CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
    static extern uint CM_Get_Device_Interface_List_ExW(
        ref Guid interfaceClassGuid,
        string deviceID,
        IntPtr buffer,
        uint bufferLength,
        uint flags,
        IntPtr hMachine);

    // this is where we are intercepting all API accesses!
    static uint CM_Get_Device_Interface_List_Ex_Hooked(
        ref Guid interfaceClassGuid,
        string deviceID,
        IntPtr buffer,
        uint bufferLength,
        uint flags,
        IntPtr hMachine)
    {
        // pass-through original API
        uint ret = CM_Get_Device_Interface_List_ExW(
            ref interfaceClassGuid,
            deviceID,
            buffer,
            bufferLength,
            flags,
            hMachine);
        // do custom logic here and re-arrange "buffer"
        return ret;
    }
}
```