# Hide devices from the program

Tags: windows, winapi, hook

I have three webcams installed in my system. I need one program to see only two of them, and the second only one. I know how to get a list of webcams using the CLSID_VideoInputDeviceCategory filter, most likely these programs get it in the same way. Can I put a hook to get a list of cameras or use other WinAPI tools so that some devices are not shown ?

Answer (score 0):

Solution using `CLSID_VideoInputDeviceCategory` get capture devices via [`IEnumMoniker::Next`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/directshow/selecting-a-capture-device) API.

Hooking this API seems what you are looking for.

Refer to ["Monitoring and instrumenting API calls using Detours"](https://github.com/microsoft/Detours), ["make webcam device invisible to a process"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52728671/make-webcam-device-invisible-to-a-process)